# calling objective C method in callback function

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

I have been working with Dragonmobile sdk and Audio Sound System, trying to make speech recognition -> text to speech chain.

and here is my code:

(there is voice recognition part up here)

```
- (void)recognizer:(SKRecognizer *)recognizer didFinishWithResults:{ 
...
SystemSoundID id = [self playSound:url2]; //playSound
    AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion (
                                           id,
                                           NULL,
                                           NULL,
                                           detectSoundFinish,
                                           NULL
                                           );
...
}

- (void)performRecognition:(id)sender
{
    if (!recognizer){
        self.recognizer = [[SKRecognizer alloc] initWithType:SKDictationRecognizerType detection:SKLongEndOfSpeechDetection language:@"en_US" delegate:self];
    }
}

void detectSoundFinish ( SystemSoundID  ssID, void *clientData )
{
    printf("end\n");
    //I want to call performRecognition here, or an equivalent thing.
}
```

I'm new to objective C(and even C. I mainly code in Python), and I understand callback function doesn't belong to my class. So, my questions are
1. Is there a way to call objc method in callback function?
2. or, a way to access properties of the main class from callback?
I've been doing searching and trying all day, but haven't figured out how to do it exactly.
Thank you!

Comment: The normal thing in Objective-C is to use "delegate" classes instead of function pointers for callbacks.  Where a function pointer is needed for compatibility with some non-Objective-C tool set, the thing to do is make use of regular C or C++ facilities and then link to Objective-C, similar to what Merlevede describes.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use an Objective-C function as a callback to a C function.

What you can do is use the last parameter, designed to pass any data you want, to pass a pointer to your class instance.

```
AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion (id,
                                       NULL,
                                       NULL,
                                       MyAudioServicesSystemSoundCompletionProc,
                                       self);
```

and inside the C callback function body, cast the pointer to your class, and use it!

```
void MyAudioServicesSystemSoundCompletionProc (SystemSoundID ssID, void *clientData);
{
    MyClass *obj = (MyClass*)clientData;
    // use obj in the normal Objective-C way!!!
}
```

Comment: `You cannot use an Objective-C function as a callback to a C function.`  Not true!  Get the thing's IMP function pointer and you can pass that to any C function accepting the appropriate signature.